# SettingWithCopyWarning unsual behavior in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe  say **release_dates**

**release_dates**

[image]

I did the filtering using some conditions and called it **b**

```
b = release_dates[(release_dates.title.str.startswith('The Hobbit')) &
                       (release_dates.country =='USA')]
```

[image]

Now I want other column that display month by extracting it from date column.
I used the below command which worked fine but threw an error

```
b['month'] = b['date'].dt.month #code1


C:\Users\user110244\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:288: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

[image]

I read the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) as suggested by the code and from my understanding I came to know that I should use the **below command** (in case of chain indexing) because using the **above command** makes it very hard to predict whether it will return a view or a copy (it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees) and code2 is much more efficient than code1 as per documentation.

```
b.loc[:,'month']=b.loc[:,'date'].dt.month #code2
```

But using this also throwing the same error.

**Can someone please explain why this is happening and How do I am assured that my code is correct in both the cases 'a' and 'b'?**
**How do I turn this warning off ?**

One more thing I want to point out i.e. I used the same code with different condition and didn't get any error

```
a =release_dates[(release_dates.title.str.contains('Christmas'))&                              
                 (release_dates.country =='USA')].sort_values('year')
a['month'] = a['date'].dt.month
a.head()
```

Comment: You should set `b` to the mask as opposed to the filtered result from the mask `b= (release_dates.title.str.startswith('The Hobbit')) &
                       (release_dates.country =='USA')` then you can do `release_dates.loc[b, 'month'] = release_dates['date'].dt.month`

Comment: regarding your latter example you made an additional call of `sort_values` on the filtered result, this returned a copy of the data, so you are then operating on a copy of the filtered results hence no warning

Comment: @EdChum can you please explain the point 1 in more detail. I am not getting the reason behind doing your way. New to pandas.

Comment: `(release_dates.title.str.startswith('The Hobbit')) & (release_dates.country =='USA')` is a boolean mask rather that what you did was the filtered result, but you then tried to add a new column to this filtered result, pandas warns you that you may or may not operating on a view of the original df, by doing what I suggested there is no ambiguity as you pass a mask to `loc` on the original data so you update the original df, however if your intention is to work on a copy then call `.copy()` on the filtered result in your code

Comment: like this: `b = release_dates[(release_dates.title.str.startswith('The Hobbit')) &
                       (release_dates.country =='USA')].copy()`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Edchum . Any way to ignore the error in case I my that I am working on a copy or modifying the original dataframe.

Comment: You are either working on a copy or a view but you need to be explicit, calling `copy()` will mean you operate on a copy, by using a mask like I suggested will ensure you operate on a view of the original df, the warnings are raised for a reason to warn you that it may not be doing what you're intending

Answer (score 1):

As Edchum explained it clearly in his comments that you used **.sort()** in the first code which lets python know that user know, it is a copy rather than a view.

Whenever we perform slicing or filtering We get either a View or a copy.However, Pandas docs do not specify any rules about what you should expect a View or a Copy.

Let me try to expand it a bit.
One simple way to avoid such warning is to use **.copy()**

```
b = (release_dates.title.str.startswith('The Hobbit')) & 
     (release_dates.country =='USA')

b1 = b.copy()
b1['month'] = b1['date'].dt.month #code1
```

By doing this you are explicitly telling Python that you what you are working on i.e. on a view or on a copy and Python will not display warning.

But please keep in mind that making copy every time consumes lot of memory. So do it whenever it is necessary.

You can also check whether two objects are pointing out to the same memory or not by using

```
np.may_share_memory(b,b1)
False
```

One other way of turning the warning off for a particular object is using **.is_copy()=False**
In this case we can use

```
b.is_copy()= False
```